# Match a string in a regex character class?

Tags: regex

For example, if I wanted to match..

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-%2B]
```

Is there a way for it to treat `%2B` as a single character such that it would match:

```
aBc_123_%2B
```

but not

```
aBc_123_%
```

More examples:

```
aBc_123_%2C - NO
aBc_%3B123_ - NO
abC_%B213_ - NO
abc_%123_ - NO
aBc%2B_123_ - YES
```

Comment: Can you give multiple example of correct and incorrect text to know how you want it to work

Comment: By the laws of nature, _character classes_ match characters, not strings.

Comment: `%2B` is 3 characters, not a single character. Or is it a single character by pre-replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `|` to match multiple expressions:

```
(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9_]|%2B)+
```

Comment: If you reference groups, it may be convenient to use a non-capturing group for alternation/repetition: `(?:...)`

Comment: I guess the answer is that no, one cannot match strings inside character classes? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) here to separate expressions.

```
^(?i:[a-z0-9_-]|%2B)+$
```

Regular Expression:

```
^                the beginning of the string
(?i:             group, but do not capture (case-insensitive) (1 or more times):
  [a-z0-9_-]       any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9', '_', '-'
 |                OR
  %2B              '%2B'
)+               end of grouping
$                before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dA2dA8)